# Search specific websites (set dynamically) using Google CSE API

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

Aside from the CSE control panel, is there anyway to specify a website to search as an API request parameter?

I've tried setting the parameter siteSearch=..., and including site:... inside the actual search query, but with these the search returned 0 results.

Otherwise, is there any way to edit the list of websites to search inside the CSE settings, programatically?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can use Google CSE Api (Customsearch.Cse.List) methods:   `setSiteSearch("siteToSearch")` and `setSiteSearchFilter("i")`.
Possible values for `setSiteSearchFilter` are `"i"`(include) and `"e"`(exclude).